# Retrieve selected group from native contact application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am working on one application in which I need to show contacts from the contact application.

I have successfully implemented the functionality but now I need to only show the contacts from the groups which are selected in native contact application similar Magic Jack(http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/free-calls-with-magicjack/id463926997?mt=8) iPhone app.

I have tried to search on google, forums, apple's documentation but didn't able to find the solution. Can anyone help me?

I am using below code to fetch all contact information.

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate(); 
ABRecordRef source = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBook); 
NSArray *persons = (NSArray *)(ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook, source, kABPersonSortByFirstName));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is code you can use,it fetch the first and last name.

```
-(IBAction)handlingClick:(id)sender
{
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *peopleController = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    peopleController.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:peopleController animated:YES];
    [peopleController release];

}

-(void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
{
    [peoplePicker  dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
     shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person 
                               property:(ABPropertyID)property 
                             identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{
    return NO;
}

-(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
     shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    self.firstName.text = (NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    self.lastName.text = (NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    return NO;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I am not using the Addressbook UI. i am fetching contact list using code. Belowis the code for.     ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    
    ABRecordRef source = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBook);
    NSArray *persons = (NSArray *)(ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook, source, kABPersonSortByFirstName));

Comment: hope you will find the ans helpful,you didn't accept this ans, is any thing wrong?.Please let me know.you can vote up if it was helpful and valid.

Comment: Sandy please check my question and comment again. I hope you can understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

Is ABGroupCopyArrayOfAllMembers not suitable for what you want?

Comment: It will contact all groups. I need only those contact groups which are selectd in native contact application. Magic jack application is doing the same.

Comment: Right. Couldn't find a glue yet. Even in NSUserDefaults nothing is mentioned about a selected group.

Comment: Yes correct. There isn't any clue. I have tried to find on forums, apple documentation but didn't get the answer. I am sure there will be a single line of command for the same.