# Not creating address book object

Tags: iphone, addressbook

I have implemented the code to get contact list form address book. For that I have used this code

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate( );
CFArrayRef allSources = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople( addressBook );
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount( addressBook );
```

and when this code is executing then my app is crashing and in crash report I got that

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000000000defe
Crashed Thread:  5
```

And I am testing on iPhone 3GS with ios 6.0.

So how I fix this bug?

Comment: When I read the title, I thought OP was aaking how *not* to create an address book...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code ,it will give you the objects list.

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate(); 
ABRecordRef source = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBook);
NSArray *persons = (NSArray *)(ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook, source, kABPersonSortByFirstName));
```

Comment: I am getting nil value in address book while i have 152 contacts in address book.

Comment: i am getting as i have one contact.Check for other property.

Comment: Please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985317/retrieve-selected-group-from-native-contact-application/11986219#11986219), i have given one ans try that.It may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for support and I got the solution. Solution of my issue is

> ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

This is deprecated in ios 6.0.